# Navigation Drawer com duplicidade

Tags: android

Tenho um NavigationDrawer com dois EditText e gostaria que esses dois campos demonstra-se os dados do usuário o nome e email, porém na minha classe TelaPrincipal quando tento jogar a informação para um dos dois campo é demonstrada duas vezes o NavigationDrawer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/telaprincipal_nav_header_et_meuperfil"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        style="@style/TextoMenuDrawerTituloPerfil"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nav_header_telaprincipal_tv_nome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/TextoMenuDrawerTitulo"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nav_header_telaprincipal_tv_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            style="@style/TextoMenuDrawerNormal"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Classe Java

```
public class TelaPrincipal extends BaseActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    //Componentes da Activity
    private Context mContext;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private View mView;
    private TextView tvNome;
    private TextView tvEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.telaprincipal);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Titulo da Activity
        setTitle(getString(R.string.telaprincipal_titulo_activity));

        //inicializando as variaveis
        inicializaVariavel();
        inicializaAcao();

        //Método do Navegation Drawer
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.telaprincipal_drawer_aberto, R.string.telaprincipal_drawer_fechado);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_header_tela_principal, navigationView, false);

        tvNome = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.nav_header_telaprincipal_tv_nome);
        tvEmail = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.nav_header_telaprincipal_tv_email);

        tvNome.setText("Denis");
        tvNome.setText("dnsfirmino@gmail.com");

        navigationView.addHeaderView(mView);
    }
```

Comment: Já observou esse trecho de código? `tvNome.setText("Denis");
        tvNome.setText("dnsfirmino@gmail.com");`

Comment: Olá Luídne, como eu disse esta duplicando a Navigation Drawer a informação do nome e email esta demonstrando, porém a duplicidade esta errada, vou tentar colocar a imagem do app para facilitar o entendimento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom dia! Tudo bem? Existem 2 erros no seu código, vamos ver o primeiro:

Você possui no seu layout da tela principal, um NavigationView que você deu o id `nav_view` então note o seguinte, nele você ja tem definido o header, mas no seu código você está inflando um header a mais! Logo existem dois headers no seu drawer, ou quantos você desejar inflar! **Existem duas formas de corrigir isso**, use a que você achar melhor:

**Forma 1:** Simplesmente remova o header que tem dentro do `nav_view` no layout retirando a linha:

```
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_tela_principal"
```

Mantendo o código exatamente do jeito que está, não terá mais o problema de duplicação do seu header.

**Forma 2:** Removendo estas linhas de código:

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
    mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_header_tela_principal, navigationView, false);

//O código entre estes dois trechos não deve ser alterado!

    navigationView.addHeaderView(mView);
```

**Substituindo por:**

```
    mView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
```

com isso ele vai obter o primeiro header definido no layout, a partir disso, segue com seu código normalmente.

Qualquer uma das duas formas vai resolver o seu problema.

Ja o seu segundo problema, note que você está definindo o texto do `TextView` `tvNome` duas vezes como observado pelo @Luídne!

Comment: Obrigado Furflez resolveu meu problema com a primeira solução.